# Как сделать такой закруглённый бордер?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такой закруглённый бордер только при помощи css?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Через `border-{side}` указать трем сторонам цвет, четвертую сделать прозрачной. А чтобы повернуть круг на нужный градус используем `transform: rotate`

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-left-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как то вот так

```css
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: не правильно сделали